# textarea corner resize icon not hiding even when the popup above the textarea have large z-index..

Tags: html, css, macos, google-chrome, textarea

I am working in a page, which contain textarea and a button, When click on button, i have to show popup.

When popup is open, the textarea right-bottom corner resize icon is visible over the popup, even though the popup have large z-index.

This issue is reproduce only mac osx 10.9.5 chrome browser.

Thanks in advance

[Here is the screen shot of the popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6j1Ik.png)

Comment: What code have you used? Post it

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but more of a bad work-around: hide the thing..

```
textarea {resize: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem still persists.

I have found a resolution for this issue after a lot of tries.
This may look very tricky. But trust me this works.

```
<i class="test"></i>
.test:after {
   content: "";
    position: absolute;
    animation: .3s ease-out forwards toggle-icon-off;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Style your popup as follows

```
.mypopup {
  z-index: 1; 
 }
```

Comment: Should never use z index to solve these type of issue, the problem here we have is around text area, so we should solve it with text area only